# All column names are in one cell

Tags: r

This is the code. The point is to find blank rows in one column, in this case defined as Address.1, and replace that with a corresponding row from one of two other columns, defined here as RF_MS_Address1 and RF_GHQ_Address1:

```
Withblanks <- read.csv("file.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

fun <- function(x, y, z) {
  y[y == ""] <- z[y == ""] #substitute missings in y with values from z
  x[x == ""] <- y[x == ""] #substitute missings in x with values from y
  x #return
}

Noblanks <- within(Withblanks, "Address.1" <- fun("Address.1", "RF_MS_Address1", "RF_GHQ_Address1"))
write.table(Noblanks, "file.csv", sep = ",", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

The resultant file has the headers in a single cell, all separated by a period. Example: "ContactID.Email.Address.First.Name.Middle.Name.etc." Naturally I want them all to be in separate cells, as right now the file is unusable. What exactly am I doing wrong to get this result?

This is a sample representation of the first row:

```
ContactID.Email.Address.First.Name.Middle.Name.Last.Name.Company.Address.1.Address.2.Address.3.City.State.or.Province.Zip.or.Postal.Code.Country.Business.Phone.Mobile.Phone.Fax.Title.Salutation.Ticker.Symbol.Language.Salesperson.SFDCContactID.SFDCLea ...
    1 1 1 2393392 emailemail@email.net Firstname  lastname 868 Management Company 1B, Plaza Place, 12 Location Road, City, City   City City City City  City City +111 11111111   Principal  NA   22222222222222   8/1/2013 0:30 5/29/2015 12:06 LLLL0909090909 ContactID.Email.Address.First.Name.Middle.Name.Last.Name.Company.Address.1.Address.2.Address.3.City.State.or.Province.Zip.or.Postal.Code.Country.Business.Phone.Mobile.Phone.Fax.Title.Salutation.Ticker.Symbol.Language.Salesperson.SFDCContactID.SFDCLea ...
1 1 1 2393392 emailemail@email.net Firstname  lastname 868 Management Company 1B, Plaza Place, 12 Location Road, City, City   City City City City  City City +111 11111111   Principal  NA   22222222222222   8/1/2013 0:30 5/29/2015 12:06 LLLL0909090909 0909090909OPK 5/28/2015 22:20    NA NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA  GUD 565787   NA NA NA NA  NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA Other  (specify in description box)            0 capital.net firstname lastname  567234 Portfolio Management  Region 0 0   MGT D 4 D4 3/8/2014 2:09 NA firstlastletters     FALSE  Cash NA Cash Cash   NA NA NA    NA 10/11/2013 4:52  contact name 9584639474UcOn 4/14/2014 3:57       9584639474UcOn     9584639474UcOn 9584639474UcOn 9584639474UcOn 9584639474UcOn9584639474UcOn contact name Pos ition,  Sales (356) 782-983 email@email.com 9584639474UcOn 2- Warm  0 242  0  6 Attempts/No Contact Website Rejected   9584639474UcOn contact name 0  Geo Region  0        Product 0  NA  Region 8/1/2013 0:17 1/11/2014 6:49  NA email@email.com         NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA           NA NA NA NA      NA NA NA            NA  9584639474UcOn  5/25/2015 0:00 12/12/2014 0:00 5/25/2015 0:00   NA  NA  NA Address 1 Address.1 5/28/2015 22:20    NA NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA  GUD 565787   NA NA NA NA  NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA Other  (specify in description box)            0 capital.net firstname lastname  567234 Portfolio Management  Region 0 0   MGT D 4 D4 3/8/2014 2:09 NA firstlastletters     FALSE  Cash NA Cash Cash   NA NA NA    NA 10/11/2013 4:52  contact name 9584639474UcOn 4/14/2014 3:57       9584639474UcOn     9584639474UcOn 9584639474UcOn 9584639474UcOn 9584639474UcOn9584639474UcOn contact name Pos ition,  Sales (356) 782-983 email@email.com 9584639474UcOn 2- Warm  0 242  0  6 Attempts/No Contact Website Rejected   9584639474UcOn contact name 0  Geo Region  0        Product 0  NA  Region 8/1/2013 0:17 1/11/2014 6:49  NA email@email.com         NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA           NA NA NA NA      NA NA NA            NA  9584639474UcOn  5/25/2015 0:00 12/12/2014 0:00 5/25/2015 0:00   NA  NA  NA Address 1 Address.1
```

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your dataset, i.e. `head(Noblanks)`?

Comment: I will try. It's a massive dataset so cleaning it up for viewing is difficult

Comment: The head of the first few columns should be enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just do: head file.csv in the OS command line

Comment: It's better to provide the head of the R dataset being output to the csv rather than providing the head of the csv.

Comment: I agreee with @AlexA. It seems the problem is likely in the `Noblanks` data.frame. Sounds like it's already been reduced to a single column (`ncol(Noblanks)==1`?)

Comment: Ok yeah that's part of the issue. It actually says there's 3 columns, which is still wrong.

Comment: Well then it's clear the problem isn't in the `write.table` command. Your `Noblanks` data frame is messed up. However, you haven't shared any of the code where you create that object. You should take a few steps back and check that you are creating that object correctly.

Comment: Fair point, so I've added all of it. It's pretty short.

Comment: It's impossible to help you without sample data from `file.csv` or `Withblanks` when you read it.

Comment: Yeah I'll add that soon. Having data won't necessarily be helpful though, the full file has over 50 columns, and my function reduces it down to three. I think the key is in the "fun" function but I'm having trouble figuring out what's happening there